# How to read the content of an XML tag

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

How to read the content of this XML?

```
<Locations>
<Location>4</Location>
</Locations>
```

I can parse it, and it works, but I can't access the value of `Location` (`4`). I'm using:

```
ZoneCheck *azone;
NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", azone.location];
```

Comment: what language are you using?  c#, java, c++, javascript???

Comment: I'm going to guess Objective-C, based on the beginnings of a code sample that are dangling at the bottom of the question.

Comment: yes iphone

i got it if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"]) {
  
  [appDelegate.zone addObject:currentElementValue];
  
  [aZonecheck setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];


Thanks

Comment: There's nowhere near enough info to answer this question.  How are you parsing the XML?  Are you using NSXMLParser?

Answer (score 0):

I have already posted the answer please follow the following link '[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877374/how-to-parse-the-attributes-like-in-this-xml-file-through-xml-parser/10877758#10877758'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877374/how-to-parse-the-attributes-like-in-this-xml-file-through-xml-parser/10877758#10877758)

First take a bool variable. and then write the following code. perhaps it will help you I have done the related work , a few days ago.

First .h file

```
@interface EventsViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *_locationArray;
    BOOL isLocation;
}
```

Then in .m file you should write this.

//In ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _locationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlString];
    NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

// Now In xml Parser Delegate Methods
pragma mark - NSXMLParser Delegate Method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Locations"]) {
        isLocation = YES;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"] && isLocation){
        NSLog(@"Location is: %@ ",elementName);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
   if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"] && isLocation){
        NSLog(@"Location is: %@ ",string);
        [locationArray addObject:string];  
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Location"]) {
        isLocation=NO;
    }
}
```

Note: At the end _locationArray will be having all the location's id's.