# how to parse the attributes like in this xml file through xml parser

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

XML FILE CODE:

```
  <Books>
  <Book id="1" isbn="123456">
  <name>Let Us C</name>
  <authors>
  <author>Yashwant Kanetkar</author>
  <author>ABC</author>
  </authors>
  <price>250.00</price>
  </Book>
  <Book id="2" isbn="345678">
  <name>Programing With C++</name>
  <authors>
  <author>Balaguruswamy</author>
  <author>XYZ</author>
  </authors>
  <price>400.00</price>
  </Book>
  <Book id="3" isbn="789012">
  <name>Professional iPhone and iPad Application Development</name>
  <authors>
  <author>Gene Backlin</author>
  <author>QWE</author>
  </authors>
  <price>550.00</price>
  </Book>
  <Book id="4" isbn="901234">
  <name>Beginning iOS 4 Application Development</name>
  <authors>
  <author>Wei-Meng Lee</author>
  <author>IOP</author>
  </authors>
  <price>500.00</price>
  </Book>
  </Books>
```

Can anyone pls help me with this?

I'm using this code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) 
    {
        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"]) 
    {
        aBook = [[Book alloc] init];
        aBook.bookID = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        aBook.isbn = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"isbn"] integerValue];
        NSLog(@"Reading isbn value : %@", aBook.isbn);
        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%i", aBook.bookID);
    }
    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First take a bool variable. and then write the following code. perhaps it will help you I have done the related work , a few days ago.

First .h file

```
@interface EventsViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *_idArray;
    NSMutableArray *_isbnArray;
    BOOL isBook;
}
```

Then in .m file you should write this.

//In ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _isbnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    NSString *xmlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"today_in_history_short" ofType:@"xml"];
    NSURL * fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:xmlString];
    NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

// Now In xml Parser Delegate Methods

## pragma mark - NSXMLParser Delegate Method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        isBook = YES;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Book"] && isBook){
        NSString *idString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *isbnString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"isbn"];
        [_idArray addObject:idString];
        [_isbnArray addObject:isbnString];
        NSLog(@"Book id is: %@ and Book isbn is: %@",idString,isbnString);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Books"]) {
        isBook=NO;
        NSLog(@"Id Array count is :%d",[_idArray count]);
    }
}
```

Note: I have check it , It's working , you can use it in you code , if still it's won't working then there will be something else wrong in your project, you can verify it by making separate project.

Comment: not working...! even other things doesn't display after applying this code...!

Comment: It should work, define the above three line at class level. and if/else in the start method.

Comment: Email me your code at "khalid0491@gmail.com" I will write code for you.

Comment: I have done it. Read your xml file and show print the data , it's working . I am going to update my answer. Accept it and vote up if it really helped you.

Comment: Check it , If it didn't helped you , then I will wdit your code.

Comment: initially it was app was crashing but after applying this code it doesn't crash but it's having some problem with parser...! It shows error message...it doesn't read the data from xml file...!

Comment: Use an array rather than just a string for authors. Then show them accordingly.